# Is there a way to make Disqus notify an entry author when a new comment is posted?

Tags: users, plugins, comments

I'm setting up a multiple authors blog and one of the requirements provided is that authors be notified when someone posts a new comment. We're planning to use Disqus for comments, and that will notify the moderators in Disqus by default, but it's not really an option for us to add all authors in craft as moderators in Disques. Maybe this is just a limitation with Disqus.

In googling for an answer it seems that someone found a way to do this in Wordpress with a plugin. (http://wpdailybits.com/blog/notify-post-author-for-new-comment-disqus/45) Would it be possible to do something similar in Craft perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disqus has a [callback function](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466258-capturing-disqus-commenting-activity-via-callbacks) that you can use to fire an email off to the author. Within that callback, you could make an AJAX request to another template which sends an email.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That seems like a good way to do it. I'll look into that.

Comment: Reviving this thread: how did you and up using Disqus Dave?